# Extra boolean set fields in java generated file using thrift

Tags: java, thrift

I have a thrift file point.thrift that has only two variables as follows:

```
struct Point {
  1: double lat,
  2: double lon
}
```

But when I generate the java file using,

```
thrift --gen java point.thrift
```

then the generated java code has other boolean variables, setLat and setLon. So, my Point object looks like below:

```
"point": {
  "lat": 12.983451879142935,
  "lon": 77.75181960314512,
  "setLat": true,
  "setLon": true
}
```

Is there any way these extra boolean variables can be removed from my point object because it is increasing the size of my object, which in turn will take up a lot of space when I store them. Note that this is the basic definition but the actual definition will have lots of other fields. So, storage is a concern for me.

Comment: What version are you using? I only get a `__isset_bitfield` (with master)

Comment: I'm using 0.10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Thrift compiler generates a bitset to determine, what fields are set or not set. The background for these lies in what codesf already said: requiredness.

In short: Thrift supports three kinds of requiredness, `optional`, `required` and a third one called "default" requiredness. The latter takes place when there is no explicit `optional` or `required` specification. The Thrift runtime libraries use these flags to determine, whether or not a particular field has been assigned a value.

In the case of Java, the implementation obviously always generates these "isset" bits, no matter what requiredness you specify.

Comment: So are you saying that there is no way of getting rid of these extra boolean variables?

Comment: I'm afraid this is the case. You could try your luck and check out, if the flags are really USED with `required`, as codesf suggested and [patch the Thrift compiler accordingly](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git). But be sure to check whether [`required`is really what you want](https://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/#_defining_structs).

Comment: I've checked with `required` but the problem still persists. Guess I'll have to manually store the objects to a different POJO before actually pushing them to the storehouse. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for "required"?

```
user@ubuntu:~/test$ cat point.thrift
struct Point {
  1: required double lat,
  2: required double lon}
user@ubuntu:~/test$ thrift -gen java point.thrift 
user@ubuntu:~/test$ cat gen-java/Point.java | grep public | grep -v '{'
  public double lat; // required
  public double lon; // required
  public static final java.util.Map<_Fields, org.apache.thrift.meta_data.FieldMetaData> metaDataMap;
  public Point(
user@ubuntu:~/test$
```

Required means the field must always be present so make sure the semantics fit.

Comment: But even with required the bitset is still generated. It is in fact in all three cases. Plus it may not meet the requirements of the use case, as you might know :-) `required` is a tricky thing.

Comment: @JensG, exactly. The boolean variables are still there.